# Android MultiAutoCompleteTextView Custom Data

Tags: android

I implemented a MultiAutoCompleteTextView with custom datas. I explain my MultiAutoCompleteTextView allow me to search toys.

```
ArrayAdapter<Toys> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Toys>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mToys) {

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {

            convertView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.toys_autocomplete_view, parent, false);
        }
        CustomTextView mToyName = (CustomTextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.mToyName );
        CircleImageView mToyImg = (CircleImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.mToyImg );
        Toy t = this.getItem(position);
        mToyName .setText(t.getName());
        ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(t.getAvatar().getThumb(), mToyImg );

        return convertView;
    }
};

mAutoComplete.setThreshold(1);
mAutoComplete.setAdapter(adapter);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
mAutoComplete.setTokenizer(new MultiAutoCompleteTextView.CommaTokenizer());
```

So my dropdown list is custom with toy's name and toy's picture but when i select a toy in the list the MultiAutoCompleteTextView displays "mypackagename".Toy."Hexadecimal" and i want to custom the display result.

Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may override your `toString()` method in your Toy class to return for example the name of the toy.

Comment: Yes, thank you it works with the toy name. But can i have the possibility to inflate a view in the toString method and using the same layout that i'm use with the dropdown ?

Comment: No, that neither possible nor desirable. This would mix up model class and view class. This is the responsibility of the adapter, to bind them.

Comment: So how can i do ? I can't create an adapter for this.